# Retrive value of association tables in EF 6 design first

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-4

we develop database in design first entity framework 6,we have doctor and clinic table have many-to-many relation with each other. In database it generated clinicdoctor table have clinic id and doctorid. we want to retrive value from clinicdoctor table

```
public partial class Doctor
    {
        public Doctor()
        {
            this.Patients = new HashSet<Patient>();
            this.Presriptions = new HashSet<Prescription>();
            this.Clinics = new HashSet<Clinic>();
        }

    public int DoctorId { get; set; }
    public string DoctorName { get; set; }
    public string Specialist { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Clinic> Clinics { get; set; }

}
```

we want to retrieve all clinic had associated to that doctor using generic Repository Get(doctorId) method

```
var clinics = unitOfWork.ClinincRepository.Get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use ClinicDoctorRepository with eager loading

```
var clinics = unitOfWork.ClinicDoctorRepository.Include("Clinics").Where(m => m.DoctorId == doctorId).Get();
```

It would make an inner join in database between ClinicDoctor AND Clinics based on ClinicsId present in ClinicDoctor table and would apply a search on DocotorId in ClinicDoctor table

**EDIT**

Please follow this [link to msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx)

Comment: Thanks @Ashish can you give me some more description or link on eager loading